# Create indicators of specific changes between rows in several columns

Tags: r

I want to create indicators of *transitions between specific values between consecutive rows*, for several different columns in a data frame.

Some sample data:

```
structure(list(Year = 1998:2007, Pregnant = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    Infection = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("Negative", "Positive"), class = "factor"), 
    Keep = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Pregnant", "Infection", "Keep"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

#    Year Pregnant Infection Keep
# 1  1998      Yes  Positive    0
# 2  1999      Yes  Positive    0
# 3  2000       No  Negative    0
# 4  2001       No  Negative    1 # Infection changes from Negative to Positive 
# 5  2002       No  Positive    1
# 6  2003       No  Positive    0
# 7  2004       No  Negative    0
# 8  2005       No  Negative    1 # Pregnant changes from No to Yes
# 9  2006      Yes  Negative    1
# 10 2007      Yes  Negative    0
```

I would like to tag the rows that had a change in a specific order. For example, 
Pregnant column values changed from 'No' (row 8) to 'Yes' (row 9), and Infection column values changed from 'Negative' (row 4) to 'Positive' (row 5). So I want to tag these rows (the Keep column indicates the tagged row as 1).

There are other changes occurring in the columns, like Pregnant - Yes to No, and Infection Positive to Negative, but those changes are not important; I only want to indicate sequences of values in a specific order.

```
Variable - Pregnant, From - 'No', To - 'Yes' 
Variable - Infection, From - 'Negative', To - 'Positive'
```

I have over 20 columns, where I want to detect certain changes in each column, and create corresponding indicator variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
df %>%
    mutate(
        grp.Preg = c(diff(as.numeric(Pregnant)) > 0, 0),
        grp.Infc = c(diff(as.numeric(Infection)) > 0, 0),
        flagChangePreg = abs(grp.Preg - lag(grp.Preg, default = 0)),
        flagChangeInfc = abs(grp.Infc - lag(grp.Infc, default = 0))) %>%
    select(-grp.Preg, -grp.Infc)
#   Year Pregnant Infection Keep flagChangePreg flagChangeInfc
#1  1998      Yes  Positive    0              0              0
#2  1999      Yes  Positive    0              0              0
#3  2000       No  Negative    0              0              0
#4  2001       No  Negative    1              0              1
#5  2002       No  Positive    1              0              1
#6  2003       No  Positive    0              0              0
#7  2004       No  Negative    0              0              0
#8  2005       No  Negative    1              1              0
#9  2006      Yes  Negative    1              1              0
#10 2007      Yes  Negative    0              0              0
```

Entries in column `flagChangePreg` and `flagChangeInfc` flag rows where `Pregnant` changes from `"No"` to `"Yes"` and `Infection` changes from `"Negative"` to `"Positive"` respectively.

Comment: Thanks @Maurits, Your solution picked up the order of values as alphabetical ('No' to 'Yes'), and it works fine. But is it possible to specify the order instead of letting it assume alphabetical order?

Comment: @JeanVuda The order is determined by the order of the `factor` levels (which by default is alphabetical); to define a specific order, I would set a specific order of `factor` levels.

Answer (score 1):

Start by explicitly setting all factor levels to your desired from-to order (instead of 'hoping' that they coincide with the alphabetic sorting ;) )

By creating an *ordered* factor, you can compare consecutive rows with `<` on lead and lag versions of the data. Thus, we calculate all transitions in one go (instead of hard-coding each variable - tedious when number of columns is large).

```
# select relevant columns from original data
d <- df[ , 2:3]
# or, assuming that 'Keep' is not in original data, just remove the first column 'Year'
# d <- df[ , -1]

# set factor levels in order of from-to
d$Pregnant <- factor(d$Pregnant, levels = c("No", "Yes"), ordered = TRUE)
d$Infection <- factor(d$Infection, levels = c("Negative", "Positive"), ordered = TRUE)

# check if factor levels are 'increasing' between rows
m <- d[-nrow(d), ] < d[-1, ]

# add a FALSE row to restore dimensions
m <- rbind(rep(FALSE, ncol(m)), m)

# get indices of changes
ix <- which(m, arr.ind = TRUE)

# set also preceeding rows to TRUE
m[cbind(ix[ , 1] - 1, ix[ , 2])] <- TRUE
```

That's basically it. You may change names and coerce to numeric:

```
dimnames(m) <- list(NULL, paste0(colnames(m), "_diff"))
m <- m + 0
```

Finally, create a 'keep' column based on presence of any `1` in 'transition variables', and `cbind` to original data frame:

```
cbind(df, Keep2 = as.integer(rowSums(m) != 0), m) 

#     Year Pregnant Infection Keep Keep2 Pregnant_diff Infection_diff
# 1  1998      Yes  Positive    0     0             0              0
# 2  1999      Yes  Positive    0     0             0              0
# 3  2000       No  Negative    0     0             0              0
# 4  2001       No  Negative    1     1             0              1
# 5  2002       No  Positive    1     1             0              1
# 6  2003       No  Positive    0     0             0              0
# 7  2004       No  Negative    0     0             0              0
# 8  2005       No  Negative    1     1             1              0
# 9  2006      Yes  Negative    1     1             1              0
# 10 2007      Yes  Negative    0     0             0              0
```